# Why does Azure Logic App SQL Trigger not fire

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, azure-sql-database

I'm using the "When a row is inserted" SQL connector in my logic app workflow. I turned on change tracking on the Azure SQL DB and the table in question per requirements. The connector connects to the SQL instance okay, but never triggers when a row is inserted. No errors or indications to troubleshoot.

If change tracking is a requirement, then this connector must be polling at a certain interval the SQL function CHANGETABLE. Or does it? Or does it need certain permissions which I would expect would have been in an error message?

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

[Test workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeUT5.png)

It will trigger if I manually press the Run button, but then the output body is empty, and nothing is sent to the next step. But this is a trigger and needs to automatically trigger when a row is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

When a row is added, changed, or removed, the SQL trigger leverages [SQL change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)  capabilities to watch the SQL table for changes and launch a function.

We also have the following restrictions when activating triggers:

- For **NewItems**, a **IDENTITY** column is necessary.

The logic app was able to successfully trigger once **CHANGE_TRACKING** was enabled on the table and whenever I created a record. The logic app won't be activated if my table doesn't have **CHANGE_TRACKING** enabled.

**To enable change tracking use below query:**

```sql
--for database level
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
--for table level
ALTER TABLE tablename
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

**After this changes in table logic app is firing trigger when new row is inserted:**

[image]

Comment: So I still need an identity column with this new built-in connector? Documentation states should work with only CT enabled, which I did, but still never triggers. I know the other connector, "When an item is created (v2)" needs the identity column, but in my case we have separate PK and identity columns and are using Azure data sync from on-prem SQL to Azure SQL and it does not support identity columns that are not also the PK column. lol

Comment: yes you need an identity column in your table to work this trigger.